# Time Series Line plot out of order with plotly R with column as Date type

Tags: r, date, time-series, plotly

So due to some constraints, I am attempting to recreate some ggplot2 plots with plotly. When I try to create a time-series line graph, the line connects the points out of order

I have looked into the documentation and I made sure to coerce the  column `date` into date format, so at this point I'm not sure why this is happening. I've reproduced my dataframe below; the list `dates` comes in the format shown in the code.

```
library(zoo)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

dates = c('04.2019', '05.2019', '09.2018', '11.2018')
x = c(44,50,58,64)
y = c(69,66,45,47)
z = c(17,50,31,36)

df <- data.frame(date=dates, x=x, y=y, z=z)
df$date <- as.Date(as.yearmon(df$date), format="%m.%Y"), format="%Y-%m-%d")

plot_ly(df) %>%
  add_trace(y=~y, x=~date, type='scatter', mode='lines+markers')
```

If anyone could help me figure out why the points are connected in a "zig-zag" fashion, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: It is plotting in the order of your dates --- first is 4.2019, then 5.2019, etc. One option is to sort your dates before plotting (df <- dplyr::arrange(df, date)).

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for that. I just thought that by coercing the column to dates that plotly would know to generate the plot, as is the case with ggplot2.